# How to style virtual vertices when using the ModifyFeature control with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, symbology

I am building an Android application that uses OpenLayers embedded in a WebView.  Being mindful of the imprecision of touch interfaces I am trying to style all controls to be large and easy to operate.

I have followed the documentation on [feature styling](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) but have been unable to control the size of the virtual vertices when using the [createVertices](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.createVertices) mode of the ModifyFeature control.

By way of example consider the following style with a pointRadius of 5:

```
var customStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "black",
                    strokeColor: "red",
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    strokeWidth: 30
                });

var customStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": customStyle,
                    "select": customStyle,
                    "temporary": customStyle
                });

var polyLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon_Layer", {styleMap: customStyles });
```

[image: small grips]

Meanwhile the following has a pointRadius of 50:

```
var customStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "black",
                    strokeColor: "red",
                    pointRadius: 50,
                    strokeWidth: 30
                });
```

[image: large grips]

As you can see this has no impact on the size of the virtual vertices midway along each edge.

Does anyone know a technique to control their size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a bug in your application or you didn't provide the right part of your code. Here's an example that use OL2.13:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z22tE/

Simply draw a polygon and try to modify it. In my example, the style of the `virtualVertex` is the same as the layer's style.

Long story:

The style of the virtualVertex will always be the same as the layer's style at the moment of the control creation. The `ModifyFeature` control has a `virtualStyle` property where it stores the style of the virtual vertices. If you change the layer style after the `ModifyFeature` control creation, the virtual vertices won't get the new style.

Now if you want to style the virtual vertices separately, you can define the `virtualStyle` property after creating your `ModifyFeature` control. Example:

```
var myModify =  new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors, 
    {
        virtualStyle: OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {},
            vectors.style ||
            vectors.styleMap.createSymbolizer(null, null)
        )
    }
)

myModify.virtualStyle.fillColor = 'red';
```

Note that if you use this, you will have to manually set `fillOpacity` and `strokeOpacity`. Otherwise, you will ignore the default values (which is `0.3`).

Comment: Very helpful advice, thank you for a detailed explanation.  My `ModifyFeature` constructor was not exhibiting this behaviour, then after looking closer I found my `OpenLayers.js` was version `Release 2.14 dev`.  After rolling back to `2.13.1` I am receiving the expected behaviour.  Odd that I was running a dev version without realising it but I'm happy to have learnt about the `virtualStyle` property.  Most of the style functionality seems to be attached to the layers; It is good to know that checking the controls may offer more further customisation.

Comment: Thanks. Critical for me was that I was adding the style map after creation of the modify control.